# Find all values of $\lambda$ so that a boundary value problem has a unique solution.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-verification, numerical-methods, boundary-value-problem

> Let $(*)$ be the following boundary value problem
>   $$\begin{align}
> \begin{cases}
> -x''(t) + \lambda x(t) = r(t), \, t \in [0,1]\\
> x(0) = \alpha\\ 
> x'(1) = \beta 
> \end{cases}
> \end{align}$$
>   Find the values of $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ for which the problem above has only one solution for all $r \in \mathcal{C}([0,1])$ and arbitrary values of $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{R}$.

In order to find all values of $\lambda$, I think I should use *Fredholms' Alternative*, that is

> Or the homogeneous problem has as its only solution the trivial one, which is equivalent to $(*)$ having a unique solution for all $r \in \mathcal{C}([0,1])$ and $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{R}$, or the homogeneous problem has a non trivial solution, which is equivalent to $(*)$ having infinite solutions or non at all.

So in my case, I want to solve the homogenous problem for $\lambda$ so that its only solutions is $x(t) \equiv 0$.

The homogeneous problem is (letting $r(t) \equiv 0,\,  \alpha, \beta = 0$)
$$\begin{cases}
-x''(t) + \lambda x(t) = 0\\
x(0) = 0\\
x'(1) = 0
\end{cases}$$
which has a general solution
$$x(t) = c_1e^{\sqrt{\lambda} t} + c_2 e^{-\sqrt{\lambda}t}$$
where $c_1$ and $c_2$ satisfy 
$$\begin{cases}
c_1 + c_2 = 0\\
\sqrt{\lambda}\left(c_1e^{\sqrt{\lambda}} - c_2e^{-\sqrt{\lambda}}\right) = 0
\end{cases}$$
Now from the first conditions we get $c_1 = -c_2$, so subtituting in the second equations
$$\sqrt{\lambda}\left(c_1e^{\sqrt{\lambda}} - c_2e^{-\sqrt{\lambda}}\right) = \sqrt{\lambda}c_2\cosh(\sqrt{\lambda}) = 0 \qquad (1)$$
Since $c_2 \neq 0$, $\lambda$ must be non zero as well, since we want no solution for $(1)$. Furthermore
$$\cosh(x) = 0 \Leftrightarrow x = \left(\frac{\pi}{2} + k\pi\right)i$$
for $k = 0, 1, \dots$,so we want $\sqrt{\lambda}$ not to be of the form $\left(\frac{\pi}{2} + k\pi\right)i$, or in other words, 
$$\lambda \neq -\left(\frac{\pi}{2} + k\pi\right)^2$$

Is this reasoning correct? Thank you very much!